Word for Mac converts unicode symbols to emojis
The most annoying 'feature' of Microsoft Word for Mac (Version 16.92 (24120731)) is that it 'converts' a regular unicode symbol to an emoji, for no apparent reason, and worse, it is a violation of the unicode standard, that specifically requires an appended code for the emoji version of a symbol.
I'm using Mac OS Sequoia 15.2 and the symbol in question is ♈︎ the internationally accepted symbol for "Aries". Using this symbol in a variety of plain-text formats in the rest of the operating system produces the regular symbol as expected.  When however, you copy the said symbol into word, it infuriatingly converts it to an emoji without reason. It is also impossible to append a unicode directive to force the correct unicode character to display. Changing the font or trying different methods to copy and paste the correct symbol into Word do not correct the situation.
Using an alternative symbol defeats the point of Unicode.  I don't want to use another symbol (I'm already using several fonts and the like and I need to keep the style as consistent as possible, (1) Firstly this involves having to ensure that hundreds of pages are correct which is time-consuming. (2) secondly I'm not just using Word, but also using a publishing program and digital imaging software that handles unicode fonts correctly, but non-unicode fonts are not consistent with the diagrams and images I'm using which makes my work look unprofessional for high-quality printing. (3) This is not a 'font' problem but a software bug that Word does not present a Unicode standard character (with an optional unicode emoji) as standard unicode.

Does this help?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/474337/prevent-microsoft-word-automatically-applying-apple-color-emoji-font-substitution
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415698/stop-autocorrect-in-microsoft-office-changing-custom-symbols-to-emoji

@TomGewecke I tried these without success.  It's essential for me to use Unicode because I need consistency in various outputs.  Also, it is Word that is violating the Unicode standard - this is a bug.

So you are unable to get the right character by changing the font used for it in Word?

If that would be the solution, I wouldn't have asked here. If you tried to reproduce the bug you would see that this is not a font problem but the way word mishandles Unicode chars that have an emoji equivalent.

You are right, the old fixes no longer seem to work. Also in Sonoma and Word 16.90. Have you also asked about this and reported it in the Word forums run by its maker?

Changing the font still seems to work in the LibreOffice word clone.
